# What is wrong with this JavaScript foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
var videos = {
    a: Popcorn("#a"),
    b: Popcorn("#b"),
    c: Popcorn("#c")
}

videos.forEach(function(vid){
    if (vid.media.readyState === 4) {
    vid.currentTime(
      videos.a.currentTime()
    );
  }
});
```

For some context, I am attempting to scale-up this JSFiddle: [Synchronizing Playback of Two Videos](https://bocoup.com/blog/html5-video-synchronizing-playback-of-two-videos) so that I can play any number of videos simultaneously.

In addition, I am wondering if there is any way to apply the foreach loop to each element in the array EXCEPT for the element in the 0th index.

Comment: objects don't have a built-in `forEach` method. In the link you provided, they are doing `Popcorn.forEach`, not `videos.forEach`

Comment: `videos`  is an object not an array. `forEach` works on arrays.

Comment: You should use `Object.keys(videos)` to foreach through the keys, and use `videos[key]` to access the item

Comment: @adiga: Nitpick: _some_ objects (notably, `Array.prototype`) do have `forEach` method. This one doesn't. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects don't have forEach Method, instead you can create array of object keys & loop through the keys to access all keys & check values like this

```
Object.keys(videos).forEach((vid)=>{
    if (videos[vid].media.readyState === 4) {
        videos[vid].currentTime(
          videos.a.currentTime()
        );
      }
});
```

Comment: `Arrays don't have forEach Method` or `object` ?

Comment: My bad, Objects don't have forEach method, I made the update, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Object literals don't have a `forEach` method defined on their prototype by default. This means you either need to implement it yourself or use another method. To implement it yourself, you can define a non-enumerable method `forEach` as part of your object, which, will execute the callback function for each property in your object, passing through both the value and key to the callback:

```js
var videos = {
    a: "#a",
    b: "#b",
    c: "#c",
}

Object.defineProperty(videos, 'forEach', {
    enumerable: false,
    value:  function(f) {
      for(const key in this)
        f(this[key], key);
    }
});

videos.forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log("value:", value, "key:", key);
});
```